# Ecplipse XML refresh dependencies programmatically

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

The eclipse XML editor plugin has a button to "Reload dependencies".
I am writing a Eclipse RCP and I would like to force this procedure to be called in certain cases.

Does anyone knows how to trigger it?

I found a possibly related class:

org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.handlers.ReloadDependenciesHandler.class

I am not sure to be in the good direction...

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me... You can try adding the handler ... in your plugin.xml:

```
<handler class="org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.handlers.ReloadDependenciesHandler"
             commandId="your.command.for.reload.id">
</handler>
```

to attach it your action bar / menu in your contribution :

```
<command
             commandId="your.command.for.reload.id"
             icon="path/to/icon.gif"
             style="push">
 </command>
```

Don' forget to add `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui` as dependencies